# Bukkit Passing Variables Through Classes

Tags: variables, bukkit

I am making a Bukkit plugin, and I need to be able to get variables from other classes.  In my `Main` class I try to get a variable from my other classes, and I'm not getting any console errors, but I can't get the variables and I can't get my `CommandHandler` class to work (Enable commands).

Here is my `Main` class code:

```
package me.AngryCupcake274.EntityManager;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Server;
import org.bukkit.command.ConsoleCommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginDescriptionFile;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

// variables for testing if user wants these entities to be removed
Boolean arrow;
Boolean boat;
Boolean droppeditem;
Boolean egg;
Boolean enderpearl;
Boolean endersignal;
Boolean experienceorb;
Boolean fireball;
Boolean firework;
Boolean fishinghook;
Boolean itemframe;
Boolean leashhitch;
Boolean lightning;
Boolean minecart;
Boolean minecartchest;
Boolean minecartcommand;
Boolean minecartfurnace;
Boolean minecarthopper;
Boolean minecartmobspawner;
Boolean minecarttnt;
Boolean painting;
Boolean primedtnt;
Boolean smallfireball;
Boolean snowball;
Boolean splashpotion;
Boolean thrownexpbottle;
Boolean witherskull;

// variables for telling how long the user wants for delays
int loopdelay;
String oneminutemessage;
String oneminutecolor;
String threesecondsmessage;
String threesecondscolor;
String twosecondsmessage;
String twosecondscolor;
String onesecondmessage;
String onesecondcolor;
String finalmessage;
String finalcolor;
String oneMinWarn;

// variables for the warnings
String threeSecWarn;
String twoSecWarn;
String oneSecWarn;
String removeInfo;
String[] worldNames;
Server server = Bukkit.getServer();

// variables for players
Player cleaner;

// variables for technical messages
ConsoleCommandSender console = server.getConsoleSender();
PluginDescriptionFile pdf = this.getDescription();
String pdfEnable = ChatColor.RED + pdf.getName() + " " + ChatColor.GREEN
        + pdf.getVersion() + ChatColor.AQUA + " Enabled!";
String pdfDisable = ChatColor.RED + pdf.getName() + " " + ChatColor.GREEN
        + pdf.getVersion() + ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + " Enabled!";

// variables for in-program
int counter = 0;
int totalcounter = 0;

// variables for getting plugins
ConfigHandler ch;
CommandHandler comh;
RemoveEntities re;
CleanEntities cent;

public void onEnable(ConfigHandler ch, CommandHandler comh, RemoveEntities re, CleanEntities cent) {
    this.ch = ch;
    this.comh = comh;
    this.re = re;
    this.cent = cent;

    this.getCommand("entitymanager").setExecutor(comh);

    // test to make sure all pluigins are reachable
    console.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "EntityManager - main class enabled!");
    if (ch.test == 1) {
        console.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "ConfigHandler - class enabled!");
    }
    if (comh.test == 1) {
        console.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "CommandHandler - class enabled!");
    }
    if (re.test == 1) {
        console.sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + "RemoveEntities - class enabled!");
    }
    if (cent.test == 1) {
        console.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "CleanEntities - class enabled!");
    }
}

public void onDisable() {

}
}
```

And here is my `CommandHandler` class code:

```
package me.AngryCupcake274.EntityManager;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class CommandHandler extends JavaPlugin implements CommandExecutor {

private Main plugin;
private CleanEntities cent;

String entityname;

int test = 1;

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd,
        String commandLabel, String[] args) {
    Player p = (Player) sender;
    plugin.cleaner = (Player) sender;

    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("entitymanager")) {
        // player typed '/entitymanager'
        if (p.hasPermission("entitymanager.main")
                || p.hasPermission("entitymanager.*")
                || p.hasPermission("*.*")) {
            // player has permission

            if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("help")) {
                // player typed '/entitymanager help'
                if (p.hasPermission("entitymanager.help")
                        || p.hasPermission("entitymanager.*")
                        || p.hasPermission("*.*")) {
                    // player has permission

                    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "Help:");
                    p.sendMessage("");
                    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "'/entitymanager help' "
                            + ChatColor.RED + "for help");
                    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD
                            + "'/entitymanager entitylist [page number]' "
                            + ChatColor.RED + "for entity list");
                    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD
                            + "'/entitymanager clearentity [entity name]' "
                            + ChatColor.RED + "to remove a specific entity");
                    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD
                            + "'/entitymanager clearentity all' "
                            + ChatColor.RED + "to remove all entities");
                    // p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD +
                    // "'/entitymanager gui' "
                    // + ChatColor.RED + "to open an EntityManager GUI");
                    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Incorrect arguments!");
                    return true;
                }
                p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You don't have permissions!");
                return true;
            }

            if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("entitylist")) {
                // player typed '/entitymanager entitylist'
                if (p.hasPermission("entitymanager.entitylist")
                        || p.hasPermission("entitymanager.*")
                        || p.hasPermission("*.*")) {
                    // player has permission

                    if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase(null)
                            || args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                        // player typed '/entitymanager entitylist'
                        // or
                        // player typed '/entitymanager entitylist 1'

                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE
                                + "Entity List: Page 1/8");
                        p.sendMessage("");
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "arrow"); // 1
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "bat"); // 2
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "blaze"); // 3
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "boat"); // 4
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "cavespider"); // 5
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "chicken"); // 6
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "cow"); // 7
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "creeper"); // 8
                        // end of page 1
                    }

                    if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                        // player typed '/entitymanager entitylist 2'

                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE
                                + "Entity List: Page 2/8");
                        p.sendMessage("");
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "item"); // 1
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "egg"); // 2
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "endercrystal"); // 3
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "enderdragon"); // 4
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "enderpearl"); // 5
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "endersignal"); // 6
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "enderman"); // 7
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "experienceorb"); // 8
                        // end of page 2
                    }

                    if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
                        // player typed '/entitymanager entitylist 3'

                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE
                                + "Entity List: Page 3/8");
                        p.sendMessage("");
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "fireball"); // 1
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "firework"); // 2
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "fishinghook"); // 3
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "ghast"); // 4
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "giant"); // 5
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "horse"); // 6
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "irongolem"); // 7
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "itemframe"); // 8
                        // end of page 3
                    }

                    if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("4")) {
                        // player typed '/entitymanager entitylist 4'

                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE
                                + "Entity List: Page 4/8");
                        p.sendMessage("");
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "leashhitch"); // 1
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "lightning"); // 2
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "magmacube"); // 3
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "minecart"); // 4
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "minecartchest"); // 5
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "minecartcommand"); // 6
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "minecartfurnace"); // 7
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "minecarthopper"); // 8
                        // end of page 4
                    }

                    if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("5")) {
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE
                                + "Entity List: Page 5/8");
                        p.sendMessage("");
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "minecartmobspawner"); // 1
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "minecarttnt"); // 2
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "mushroomcow"); // 3
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "ocelot"); // 4
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "painting"); // 5
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "pig"); // 6
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "pigzombie"); // 7
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "primedtnt"); // 8
                        // end of page 5
                    }

                    if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("6")) {
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE
                                + "Entity List: Page 6/8");
                        p.sendMessage("");
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "sheep"); // 1
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "silverfish"); // 2
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "skeleton"); // 3
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "slime"); // 4
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "smallfireball"); // 5
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "snowball"); // 6
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "snowman"); // 7
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "spider"); // 8
                        // end of page 6
                    }

                    if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("7")) {
                        // player typed '/entitymanager entitylist 7'

                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE
                                + "Entity List: Page 7/8");
                        p.sendMessage("");
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "splashpotion"); // 1
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "squid"); // 2
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "thrownexpbottle"); // 3
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "villager"); // 4
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "witch"); // 5
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "wither"); // 6
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "witherskull"); // 7
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "wolf"); // 8
                        // end of page 7
                    }

                    if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("8")) {
                        // player typed '/entitymanager entitylist 8'

                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE
                                + "Entity List: Page 8/8");
                        p.sendMessage("");
                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "zombie"); // 1
                        // end of page 8
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You don't have permissions!");
                return true;
            }

            if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("clearentity")) {
                // player typed '/entitymanager clearentity'

                entityname = args[1].toLowerCase();

                switch (entityname) {

                case "arrow":
                    cent.clearArrow(); // player cleared arrows
                    break;

                case "bat":
                    cent.clearBat(); // player cleared bats
                    break;

                case "blaze":
                    cent.clearBlaze(); // player cleared blazes
                    break;

                case "boat":
                    cent.clearBoat(); // player cleared boats
                    break;

                case "cavespider":
                    cent.clearCaveSpider(); // player cleared save spiders
                    break;

                case "chicken":
                    cent.clearChicken(); // player cleared chickens
                    break;

                case "cow":
                    cent.clearCow(); // player cleared cows
                    break;

                case "creeper":
                    cent.clearCreeper(); // player cleared creepers
                    break;

                case "item":
                    cent.clearItem(); // player cleared items
                    break;

                case "egg":
                    cent.clearEgg(); // player cleared eggs'
                    break;
                }

                p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Incorrect arguments!");
                return true;
            }

            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Incorrect arguments!");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Read [onEnable() and onDisable()](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Plugin_Tutorial#onEnable.28.29_and_onDisable.28.29) and [Using a separate CommandExecutor class](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Plugin_Tutorial#Using_a_separate_CommandExecutor_class).

Comment: Before you start coding Bukkit, you should really learn the basics of Java. To answer your question, though, you can use the `static` modifier to pass variables from one class to another. For example, in the `Main` class: `public static int myVariable = 2;`, then, in your other class, you can just do `int number = Main.myVariable`. But, using the `static` modifier is a bad habit to get into, which is why you should really try completely understanding Java, first. One more thing, your `onEnable()` method in your `Main` class can not have any arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
Boolean arrow;
```

You should try

```
public static Boolean arrow;
```

It's a way of passing one variable to any other class, making it static!

You should do that to all of the variables that you want to access via other class.

Answer (score 1):

A way of getting variables from different classes would either to make the declaration `static` or make a `constructor` to call these variables.

### Static method

#### Upside

The upside to this way would be that you can call this variable from other classes with ease by entering the classname plus a dot, from there on you can get any variable/method that is static.

#### Downside

The downside to this is that *ANYTHING* can change this variable, including separate plugins. Any plugin or other jar file can change this variable and can lead to problems if another plugin does.

#### How to do it

How to do this would to just put `static` before your declaration of the variable. Example:

```
static boolean example = false;
```

### Constructor Method

#### Upside

The upside to this is that only your plugin can change it with the constructor inside of the class. Any variable inside of that class is easily accessible.

#### Downside

The downside to this is that it is more complicated than just putting `static`. It can lead to problems with setting CommandExecutors and listeners. When setting them, you have to match the constructor.

#### How to do it

To do this you would put this inside of your class file:

```
[class to import] plugin;
public [current class]([class to import] instance)
{
    plugin = instance;
}
```

The `plugin` variable will have all of the variables/methods inside of it by doing `plugin.`. Here you can call these variables with ease. To match the constructor when registering events/commands you would match the constructor like so:

```
this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new [classWithEventsToBeRegistered](this), this)
```

The class matches the constructor. This would be the same for commands.

Answer (score 0):

### Static modifier

You can make use of the `static` modifier. Normally in java you make instances of classes, each instance may have different values of the variables. Variables or methods that use the `static` modifier are directly associated with the class not the instances of the class. Every instance of that class shares the same value of the variable of method.

### Access Modifiers

No modifiers (Only visible to the package)

`private` (Only visible within the class)

`public` (Visible to the whole world including external packages)

`protected` (Visible to the package and all subclasses)

### Solution

What you may want to do as both classes are within the same package is either use no access modifier or `protected` access modifier combined with the `static` modifier so your variables would look like this:

```
static Boolean arrow;
static Boolean boat;
static Boolean droppeditem;
static Boolean egg;
static Boolean enderpearl;
static Boolean endersignal;
//or
protected static Boolean arrow;
protected static Boolean boat;
protected static Boolean droppeditem;
protected static Boolean egg;
protected static Boolean enderpearl;
protected static Boolean endersignal;
//and so on
```